# How to setup page length in inches over command for printer epson lx300

Tags: php, printing

Can anyone tell me how to setup page length in inches for epson lx300. Im using the jzebra to communicate with the printer.
I have find that i should send this over PHP: 
CHR(27).CHR(67).CHR(0).CHR(3) -> to set 3 inches page length but its not working.

I want when i finish with printing the printer to set the paper to cutter correctly. Now the printer stop on the place where i finish printing and do not pool up the paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ajax call to php script which will return base64 encoded data.
In jZebra u can use applet.append64( data );
This will prevent deleting of chr(0) char (null).

Comment: Thank you. This have solve my problem.